# How can I build trust within my team?

Tags: telecommute

I started a new position as a backend dev 8 months ago in a full remote team.
I have 3yoE with the technologies we're using in our current project.

The team consists of 4 other developers who are working in this constellation since 5 years and 1 other one who has started at the same time like me.
But I have worked most of the time in the area and technologies we are working with.

The problem seems to be that the older guys think that the new people need to learn a lot.
I have the feeling that there's not much trust into my experience. Everytime I suggest some improvements they listen to it but always say they don't like it. It feels like a conservative team spirit.

Code reviews take weeks, because they're going forth and back and when there's a discussion about the architecture and project improvement they don't invite me (neither the other new ones).

The tasks are more like something for beginners and fixing one small bug here and there or do some research, while the old team members are driving the design and architecture of the whole product.

I don't get access to the cluster, even when I ask for something and say "I know where to check it, just give me access then I can do it."

Despite of that I like the workplace and I don't want to change it. The people are usually nice and helpful.
But I want more trust and more room for my personal improvement. And I know that I can help out and do more harder tasks, so that they don't suffer so much from the deadline. When I say I'll pull this task for more experienced one they say "you should no do this".

So, how can I build up trust? After 8 months it feels more like I'm a code monkey for them and they to the big picture things.

Comment: Were you hired to do architecture and big picture things? Shy of some exceptional people, 3 years of experience is not a person I would trust to architect and design. What did your manager say when you raised the wanton for more challenging tasks?

Answer (score 4):

I think there's an excellent task for your manager here. Either your manager can tell you this is how the culture is (and you can decide whether you're a good fit), or your manager can come up with a plan together with you and/or your team to improve on this and what timeline can be expected for this.

As a bonus, you have a track record with your manager of noticing and working/improving on this. Seeing that code reviews take weeks, it could also have a negative impact on the quantity of your output. You don't want to take the fall for cultural stuff from other people.

Comment: Yeah, i guess I should talk to my manager. I think it is a good idea to let him know that I'm willing to do more stuff and take some responsibility. Then maybe he'll need to observe if the team let's me go. Otherwise I can talk to him, again.

Answer (score 4):

Any new employee starts with basic stuff, while they learn the product and the existing company processes. You build trust by learning quickly, delivering quickly, delivering good product, participating in reviews and discussions, not being arrogant, not being unrealistic, and being a comfortable person to work with.

As you show you can do what's needed, you will be asked to do more.

It really isn't that complicated.

**Addendum:** If the tasks being assigned don't change, it may simply be that those tasks need to be done, you're juniormost, and others are grabbing the more challenging tasks first. Talk to your manager about whether you can start taking more difficult stuff, even if it means that the trivial need to be shared out more evenly across the team. They may just be waiting for you to say you're ready and eager.

Comment: It depends, if they're still doing "basic" tasks after 8 months, it maybe be a sign of people not wishing to let go.

Comment: That's the problem. After 8 months the tasks didn't really change and the amount of trust neither. But I'm Always motivated and communicating a lot.

Comment: @HardWorkingLarry: See Addendum.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative mechanism for achieving some of these results is to follow the process. People will trust you when you stay within a process and demonstrate realistic expectations and deliver qualitative results (as per @keshlam).

If you document fully what you need to happen and how you'd intend to do it, continue to follow the process until it's clear that the process itself is a hinderance to good working order. Often processes are put in place to remediate some kind of organizational pain, and understanding that pain is critical to changing it. Once other folks realize that the process has become the pain, they'll be ready to engage a change.

It's also possible that you'll learn more about the processes or the reasons for the processes to exist. Either way, you'll either have a better understanding of the process (and its "why") or you'll have the access you need.